# Group by Where(field.id is the same)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, field

Table **header**

```
x---id---x---short_name---------x
|   1    |       alcatel        |
|   2    |       Nexus          |
|   3    |       ZTE            |
x--------x----------------------x
```

Table **Detail**

```
x---id---x---------code---------x---header.id---x
|   1    |         XXX          |       1       |
|   2    |         ZZZ          |       2       |
|   3    |         ZZZ          |       2       |
|   4    |         XXX          |       3       |
x--------x----------------------x---------------x
```

And I need to GROUP BY CODE Where field.id is the same, example:
In this case I get 2 rows with same field.id so I need to group by my field code just in case if field.id is the same..
(Very hard to me to explain...)

I need to get this

```
x---header.id---x--detail.id--x-----short_name----x---detail.code---x
|       1       |      1      |     alcatel      |       XXX       |
|       2       |      3      |     Nexus        |       ZZZ       |
|       3       |      4      |     ZTE          |       XXX       |
x---------------x-------------x------------------x-----------------x
```

I don't know if this is actually possible to do, but if it is please help me, if it isn't please tell me that this is impossible.

**EDIT: my *field.id* and *field.code* (the ID and CODE fields) are from a table with a relashion 1 to N called *field***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select h.id as header_id, max(d.id) as detail_id, h.short_name, d.code
from header h
join detail d on d.`header.id` = h.id
group by header_id, h.short_name, d.code
```

Comment: My bad i failed something , check the edit..
Thanks for trying help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, `field.id`, code
FROM test
GROUP BY code, `field.id`
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95cf1b/3)

Comment: My bad i failed something , check the edit..
Thanks for trying help me :)

Comment: What you get error I given also SQL fiddle check it there is no any error